# LaTeX to XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex

I am swtiching from LaTeX to XeLaTeX. Almost 10 years i didnt find any problem with PDF produced from LaTeX with resepect to Press. Will XeLaTeX result the same.

I am seeing the below information are not clear with XeLaTeX which made me to ask this question.

- PDF font encoding from Indentity H to Ansi (Ansi encoding is must for some press)
- Image loading as eps converted to PDF on the fly (will quality be the same for line art,   halftone, color images etc.)

Comment: What was your workflow? `dvi->PDF`? Also there are some other questions for these items for example, [1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107077/3235),[2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94982/3235)... as I am literally copying from the sidebar.

Comment: Have you checked out the posting [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984/5001)? Please also tell us a bit more about your computing environment, e.g., which operating system and which TeX distribution you employ.

Comment: Highly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36/differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42628/i-am-new-to-tex-should-i-use-latex-xelatex, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/the-differences-between-tex-engines/13601#13601, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22823/which-tex-should-one-use/22825#22825

Comment: Why are you switching?

Comment: Guys Apologies for the Delay. |percusse: Since I moving to XeLaTeX obviously my workflow will be direct PDF not dvi -> PDF. 2nd point i am clear but not direct answer for my 1st point ie., Indentity H to Ansi encoing |Mico: Yes i have check most of the links what are trying to say but i couldn't find proper answer for my 1st point. Operating System: Win7. TeX distrbution: MikTeX |Mario: The links which your direct me are very useful but no straight answer for my first point |cfr: To play with Unicode and open type fonts To All: XeLaTeX PDF should match all parameters as PDF generated from PS